# VS2019 Windows 10 C++ exe compatibility tool wants to run as Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2019, exe, compatibility, windows-10-desktop

I am using VS2019 (16.11.10) and have created a C++ exe using Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0. When I look at the properties of the exe in Windows 10 the compatibility tab appears and the troubleshooter wants to run the exe in Windows 8 compatibility mode.

I have added information to the embedded manifest using assembly identity:

MyCompany.MyGroup.MyApp, processorArchitecture=IA64, version=2.0.22.1,  type=win32, language=neutral

and also an extra manifest file containing...

```
 <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
         <!-- Windows 10 --> 
         <maxversiontested Id="10.0.19041.0"/>
         <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      </application> 
   </compatibility>


   
     <!-- Windows 10 -->
```

Can anyone please tell me how to find out why Windows 10 wants to run this exe in Windows 8 compatibility mode, when it runs OK as a Windows 10 exe. Many thanks.

I have tried checking the embedded manifest by opening the exe in VS2019 to verify that the information I have added actually appears, it does. I have tried making the manifest file not embedded, this makes no difference.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/276994/difference-between-ia64-and-x64

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your 'snippet' isn't passing the schema validation. Try:

1. Add a `settings.manifest` to your project that contains:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
       <application>
          <!-- Windows Vista -->
          <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
          <!-- Windows 7 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
          <!-- Windows 8 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
          <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
          <!-- Windows 10 / Windows 11 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
       </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

(once you have it working, feel free to trim it down)

2. Make sure in your project properties you have Linker -> Manifest File -> Generate Manifest set to "Yes"

(this page should be defaulted to run "asInvoker". If you need admin rights, you'd change it here).

3. In the project properties, also make sure Manifest Tool -> Input and Output -> Embed Manifest is set to "Yes".

(this is also where you'd set DPI awareness if desired)

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/)

Comment: Thanks Chuck, will have a look at this on Monday and post back here.

Comment: I have tried this (I did find a small error in the manifest file) sadly I still have the same problem. The blog post doesn't give me any more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed `assembly` top-level tag. Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                        name="MyCompany.MyGroup.MyApp"
                        version="2.0.22.1"
                        processorArchitecture="*" />
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <maxversiontested Id="10.0.19041.0"/>
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests